# Problem linking igraph: ImportError: libigraph.so.0

Tags: 14.04, dynamic-linking

After following the instructions for installing the [igraph library](http://igraph.org/c/), I obtained the following error:

```
ImportError: libigraph.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Is there a solution for this problem? I ran into the same problem on two different Ubuntu 14.04.1 installations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two solutions worked for me (tested on both Ubuntu 14.0.1 installations).

1. Following a clue on a [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17889799/libraries-in-usr-local-lib-not-found), the error went away after adding the following line to my `~/.bashrc` file:

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib"`

2. From a [suggestion on the igraph mailing list](https://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/igraph-help/2015-02/msg00063.html), running the following command after `make install` solved the problem:

`sudo ldconfig`

I don't understand the problem enough to know which of these solutions is preferred, nor why the error is happening and appears to be specific to Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks to Bradford Boyle, I learned that this problem is not specific to igraph. See [foo.so.0 linking problem](http://gnu-automake.7480.n7.nabble.com/quot-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-foo-so-0-cannot-open-shared-object-file-No-such-file-or-di-td3970.html). It would seem from that long thread that `sudo ldconfig` is preferred. I also suspect ldconfig runs on boot.